# How to put an array of javascript object in a cookie?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to put an array of Javascript objects and retrieve it again? Is there an easy way? Do I have to serialize as a String before storing them in a cookie?

The next code shows what I want to achieve:

```
writeCookie("items",[new Item(3,15.00,2,"GR-10 Senderos"),new Item(4,45,1,"GR-10 Senderos<br/>GR 88 Senderos del Jarama<br/>Camino del Cid")],5*365);
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var items = readCookie("items");
});

function writeCookie(name, value, days) {
  // By default, there is no expiration so the cookie is temporary
  var expires = "";

  // Specifying a number of days makes the cookie persistent
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }

  // Set the cookie to the name, value, and expiration date
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  // Find the specified cookie and return its value
  var searchName = name + "=";
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var c = cookies[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
      c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(searchName) == 0)
      return c.substring(searchName.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  // Erase the specified cookie
  writeCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind that cookies have size limits (the more restrictive browser it's IE, allows a maximum of 4,096 bytes per cookie http://is.gd/5kvH7), and don't forget that cookies will be sent with *every* request, that's why is recommended to have cookie-free domains for images and components. http://is.gd/5kwcx

Comment: I want to store shopping cart items, some text and quantities. I think size would not be an issue. However, thanks for the information. Appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would JSON encode it as a string, and then store that in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Heck yeah you have to serialize it as a string. Garsh! Remember, cookies are just HTTP headers which, being sent over the network, are just byte arrays. But not just any bytes. HTTP headers pretty much follow the MIME spec which only allows plain 7-bit ASCII. So serialize it, just like Marius says. Use json.org/json2.js. Or roll your own serialization with String.join.